# Python 2.7 : store the variable value permanently even when I run the session next time

Tags: python, python-2.7, jenkins

Scenario: python code which checks the number of visitors entered through a gate.
depending on that number I build the next job.

EDIT 1 :

#

file1 :( 
First Run
this file counts the number of visitors that are arriving default is 3 in my case. Now i execute the file and I found that visitors arrived are 4 . Now and export the same to file2 and print the visitor count as 4 at the same time the visitors value is changed to 4 now in file1.

Now the second run:

Now in file1 the visitors value is 4 and it is checking if visitors > 4 , now if the count is 4 then i export the same to file2 if count is 5 now then i export the same to file2 and retain the value as 5 **count of visitors completely depends on the URL) ####

```
datasource = "www.PPrestraunt.com/personsentered"
data = len(datasource) #gives me the live value of the number of persons entered
if(visitors > 3): 
   bottles = data
   visitors = bottles
   print bottles
else:
   visitors = 3
```

this above code is imported to a another file which has the working

file2:

```
from file1 import visitors
number_of_bottles = visitors
print number_of_bottles
```

I have setup the same in jenkins job so it builds every 5 mins.
In the above code the value of visitors is not changing every time I am running the code value remains 3 even though the number is increased to 4.

expected case: If value is more than 3 value should be retained in next session too and the if condition should now check for the new value ex: (if(visitors > 4)

any help is appreciated.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Persistence_(computer_science)

Comment: In short, you need to save and load that value whenever you run the process. So, perhaps a database, or maybe a simple file if it is just a number. Likely, it is good to stick with some portable text-serialization format like JSON.

Comment: Can you explain how to achieve that I have tried with the database option as sqllite(but it wont be worth for a small file like this)
another option what you said is json which I have no idea can you provide a bit insight in this about the approach.

Answer (score 0):

Like what @juanpa wrote.

Here is a small program that increments a counter, you can tailor it to your code

```
import os
data_file = "lower_bound.txt"
is_file_empty = (os.path.isfile(data_file)==False) or (os.stat(data_file).st_size == 0)
if (is_file_empty):
    with open(data_file,"w") as f:
        f.write("3");


datasource = "www.PPrestraunt.com/personsentered"
data = len(datasource) #gives me the live value of the number of persons entered
lower_bound = 0;
with open(data_file,"r") as f:
    lower_bound = int(f.read());

if (visitors>lower_bound):
    bottles = data
    visitors = bottles
    print bottles
    // @Alex either lower_bound+=1; or lower_bound = visitors not sure what you want
else: 
    visitors = lower_bound;
with open(data_file,"w") as f:
    f.write(str(lower_bound));
print lower_bound,"is the new minimum and",visitors,"is the current visitor count";
```

Comment: Thanks , here I have the reference as 3 it should not decrease in number , if the persons entered are two still i should have the bottles as 3 
so implementing the logic above can give false positives.
Idea is if the number is more than 3 It should retain the value, so that next time when I execute the code again it should never decrease from 3 but if value is increased , suppose 4 it should check the condition from 4 onwards.

Comment: so if the new value is 10 but the visitors are under 10, visitors should be 3?

Comment: No , my source url  'datasource = "www.PPrestraunt.com/personsentered" ' can give me value as anything it can be 10 or 2 too.
but when the value becomes 2 the condition 'if(visitors > 3)' should check from 3 only not from 2.

Comment: Both my files are in python extension , so will it write the data in that extension or as text ?
cant i overwrite the same py file?

Comment: it will write it as a general file, you can change data_file to

data_file = "visitor_counter.txt";

if this makes you happy :) but extension doesn't change the file contents

Comment: the code snippet u provided above should be run in file1 itself ? will it create a new file as I have to import the same in file2.

Comment: I have run the code above it checks of the file is greater than 3 but doesn't appends to the 2nd run still it takes the condition value as 3 itself.

Comment: next run compares to 4? then compare 5? 6..7.8...9..10? Depending on how many times it is greater than the requirement? Otherwise the value will be equal to the requirement?

Comment: excatly :-)
if visitors > 3 (suppose 4) is the result I got from source url then in next run the the condition it should check is visitors > 4 , now if visitors are not greater than 4 then retain the value as 4 .
but if the value i get from source url as 2 then it should retain the last value itself as 4.

Comment: @Alex i think i am very close to what you want, however you need to decide what you want for the line i commented in the // alex part. the first one will just increase the lower limit by 1 each time visitors is greater than the requirement. the 2nd one will set it to the current visitor count when it greater than the lower. try them both :)

Comment: Hey thankyou very much for the efforts.
I have edited the part from edit hope now u get the requirment :-)
once again thnks for the efforts

Comment: I am accepting the answer since It worked properly,
thanks a lot @Robert.
Just a clarification the new file which it is generating is a text file so If I import the variable from that file in python will it be a problem??

Answer (score 0):

This would be a great scenario for pickling. You can pickle data (in your case a counter) and store this data, then retrieve it at a later point in time:

```
import pickle

def your_code(counter):
    # Replace this with your code and use the counter variable.
    # Every time you execute the code it will increase
    # e.g. 3, 4, 5, 6 ....
    print(counter)

try:
    counter = pickle.load(open('counter.pckl', 'rb'))
    counter += 1
    pickle.dump(counter, open('counter.pckl', 'wb'))
    # Now execute your code with the new counter:
    your_code(counter)

except:
    counter = 3
    pickle.dump(counter, open('counter.pckl', 'wb'))
    # Execute your code for the first time. This will only happen once.
    your_code(counter)
```

The first time you execute this code, the counter will be initialized to 3. You can then call your existing code as a function and use this counter. Whenever you run the script, the counter will increase and your code will use the new version of counter: `e.g. 3, 4, 5, 6`.

Comment: Thanks but i dont want to count the execution of code, rather the data inside

Comment: So each time you run the code the number of visitors will change? What data do you want to persist between runs?

Comment: yes , that depends on my source url  if in file1 the visitors data changes to a new value (base value =3, suppose it changes to 4) then it should retain the value so that when I run file2 it takes the value 4 and not 3.

Comment: Ok so if it is 10, then it will check if its greater then 10 next time. What needs to happen if it then decreases to 5?

Comment: whatever is the value in file1 that should be stored. here is the logic

1st run
[in file 1: if b > 3 then a=b or else a =3 ; in file 2 import a.]
2nd run
[if b was >3 in first run (suppose 4) then 2nd run should check the condition b>4 ; in file 2 import a]